# Android Retrofit Bearer Token authorization

Tags: android, authorization, retrofit, okhttp, bearer-token

I'm making authorization using Retrofit + OkHttp. My user send login and password and server return him token. I need to store that token, for example in SharedPreferences, don't I? And what to do next? Because I need auto auth. I need to compare my token and server token?

Comment: what do you mean by auto Auth?

Comment: When user don't enter his login and password every time he opens the app

Comment: you should get new token once user open the app, get email and pass you stored in shared preference when user first login

Comment: But I dont want to store them, it isn't safity

Comment: then how you get the acesss token again? Have you tried saving user password using encryption technique.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the bearer token returned from your server, that token should be passed in the `Authorization` HTTP Header with value `Bearer <token_here>` to access protected server side resources.

With Retrofit 2 you can supply the HTTP header like:

```
@GET("/api/endpoint")
fun getResource(@Header("AUTHORIZATION") value: String): Call<ResponseType>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, but then I tried something like:

```
@POST("/xxx")
fun [function name](@Header("Authorization") authorization)
```

And append Bearer to your token that you're passing, like

```
createTask("Bearer ".plus(access_token))
```